# Looping through elements with similar class

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, loops

How can I loop through a set of elements  within a specific div tag? This method is defined in a factory for Angular.js code.

```
<div id="idName">

  <span class="className">Monday</span>
  <span class="className">Tuesday </span>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 var currentTime = new Date();
        var today = currentTime.getDay(); //0-7
        var d = new Date();
        var weekday = new Array(7);
        weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";

$('#idName .className').each(function(index, item) {
    if(item.text) //This part never runs
        {   
            if(item.text.indexOf(weekday[today])!=-1) { 
                item.addClass('currentDay'));
            }
            else {
                item.removeClass('currentDay');
            }
        }

        });
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No `item` has the property `text`. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: As pointed out by answers below, HTML DOM elements don't have a `text` property. See this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp. You may be confusing that with the jQuery method `.text()`. See this http://api.jquery.com/text/.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but it's really bugging me that your comment says `//0-7` instead of `//0-6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the indexOf from weekday[], not the text item (you want to know if the day is in the array).  And you have an extra space after the span containing Tuesday (so it won't be found by indexOf).  Try this:

```
<div id="idName">

<span class="className">Monday</span>
<span class="className">Tuesday</span>
</div>
```

Then update the code as follows (no changes in this section):

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var today = currentTime.getDay(); //0-7
var d = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
```

Also addClass/removeClass are not functions of item (a dom element), but of $(item)  in the each loop.

```
$('#idName .className').each(function(index, item) {
    if(item.textContent) //This part never runs
    {
        if(weekday.indexOf(item.textContent) == today) {
            $(item).addClass('currentDay');
        }
        else {
            $(item).removeClass('currentDay');
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`text` is method and not property. use `.text()` instead of `.text`. also context `this` in iteration refers to respective element in each iteration. you can use it to create jquery object of it. also you can use `toggleClass` with boolean condition to add/remove class based on condition :

```
$('#idName .className').each(function() {
  if($(this).text().length) 
    $(this).toggleClass('currentDay',$(this).text().indexOf(weekday[today])!=-1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop part is fine, the problem is that elements don't have a `text` property. You probably meant to use `$(item).text()`. Also note that `item` will just be a DOM element, not a jQuery object. And the idiomatic way to get that element is `this`, rather than `item` (unless you have to because you're using `this` for something else):

```
$('#idName .className').each(function(index) {
    var item = $(this),
        text = item.text();
    if (text) {
        if (text.indexOf(weekday[today]) != -1) {
            item.addClass('currentDay');
        } else {
            item.removeClass('currentDay');
        }
    }
});
```

*(You also had an extra `)` on the `item.addClass('currentDay');` line).*

Answer (score 0):

`$("#idName .className")` is already a collection of elements, you can go directly into `.text()`

```
$('#idName .className').text(function(i,v) {
  $(this).toggleClass("currentDay", $.trim(v)===weekday[today]);
});
```

**[*jsBin demo*](http://jsbin.com/podara/3/edit?html,css,js,console,output)**

P.S:

- you had extra `);` in your code. Use Developer Tools, Console to inspect for errors.
- `currentTime.getDay()` cannot give you ***0-7*** but `0-6` cause Sunday is `0` and **Saturday is `6`**
- Read the jQuery documentation before using methods.
- `weekday` Array can be defined as `var weekday = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];`
- Use `$.trim()` to remove unwanted *wrapping* whitespaces

Answer (score -1):

I would check for item.innerHTML instead of item.text in your if statement

Comment: You know that `innerHTML` could return (in the case one modifies a bit the HTML) into having Tags. You cannot compare a string with HTML tags like `"<b>Sunday</b>"` with i.e: `"Sunday"`

Comment: I'm just saying it would work in this situation since there's no styling on the text